# Migrating from Quartz.NET 2 to 3 Casting Error

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

My question is regarding the upgrade from Quartz.Net 2 to 3 in which now includes await/async methods.  I have followed all the instructions in the migration document but I'm having an issue at the following initializaiton (marked line):

```
 public partial class BMOSSService : ServiceBase
{
    private EventLogger _eventLogger = new EventLogger("BMOSS");
    private static ISchedulerFactory _scheduleFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    ****private static IScheduler _scheduler = _scheduleFactory.GetScheduler();****

    private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger("BlackBox.BMOSS.Scheduler");
    private static readonly ILog _logToDo = LogManager.GetLogger("BlackBox.BMOSS.Scheduler.ToDo");

    private static bool _forceStop = false;

    public BMOSSService() ...
```

I understand that the scheduler factory now needs the await instruction but the issue is that this is a global declaration and I can add the asynch keyword to the class how can I fix this? any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: do you get an error message?

Comment: yes, Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Quartz.IScheduler>' to 'Quartz.IScheduler'. An explicit conversion exists

Comment: Did you solve this? Maybe with the newer answer?

Comment: Not yet! But I thing I found the solution.  Once I finished and test it I can post the complete solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issue.  This is how I did it.  First I had to change the variable initialization from:

```
private static IScheduler _scheduler = _scheduleFactory.GetScheduler();
```

to

```
private static Task<IScheduler> _scheduler = _scheduleFactory.GetScheduler();
```

This made me change some other method implementations to return a Task and some await and everything is running now.  The trick was to receive the value like this:

```
 public async Task RegisterJobsProcessAsync(Task<IScheduler> scheduler)
        {
            _log.Info("Job registering process begins");

            this._scheduler = scheduler.Result;

            await UnRegisterJobsAsync();
            await RegisterJobsAsync();

            _log.Info("Job registering process ends");
        }
```

Comment: Glad to see it worked :) You can mark this as answer by the way

Comment: I'm glad too :). Thanks for you help!!

Answer (score 3):

In the new version, `GetScheduler()` returns a `Task<IScheduler>`, which I didn't understand at first.

In this case, you just want the result of your Task (i.e. just your `IScheduler` value), which can read as follows:

```
private static IScheduler _scheduler = _scheduleFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-task) is the official documentation.