# The type or namespace name 'Collection' does not exist in the namespace 'Quartz'

Tags: c#, quartz.net

Trying to Schedule multiple jobs using the following code

```
            // construct a scheduler factory
            ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();


            // get a scheduler
            Scheduler = schedFact.GetScheduler().GetAwaiter().GetResult();


            // define the job and tie it to our ReportSyncJob class
            IJobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<ReportSyncJob>()
                .WithIdentity("ReportSyncJob", "groupProcessQueue")
                .Build();


            // Trigger the job to run now, and then every day on weekdays
            ITrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
              .WithIdentity("ReportSyncJobTrigger", "groupProcessQueue")
              .StartNow()
              .WithCronSchedule("0 0 3 1 / 1 * ? *")
              .Build();


            // Trigger the job to run now, and then every day on weekdays
            ITrigger trigger2 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
              .WithIdentity("ReportSyncJobTrigger", "groupProcessQueue")
              .StartNow()
              .WithCronSchedule("0 0 6 1/1 * ? *")
              .Build();

       26-> var dictionary = new Dictionary<IJobDetail, Quartz.Collection.ISet<ITrigger>>();
            var dic = new Dictionary<Quartz.IJobDetail, Quartz.Collection.ISet<ITrigger>>();
            dictionary.Add(jobDetail, new Quartz.Collection.HashSet<ITrigger>()
                      {
                          trigger1,
                          trigger2
                      });
            Scheduler.ScheduleJobs(dictionary, true);
            Scheduler.Start();
```

but getting the following exception in line 26 marked by arrow in code

> The type or namespace name 'Collection' does not exist in the namespace 'Quartz' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Your kind answer will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: using System.Collections.Generic; may fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This interface `Quartz.Collection.ISet` is located [here](https://quartznet.sourceforge.io/apidoc/2.0/html/html/2a1edf2b-8764-b99c-d5bb-a30a9f286ef6.htm). Quartz (in Quartz.dll) Version: **2.2.1.400**

```
namespace Quartz.Collection
```

[API documentation link for version 2.0](https://quartznet.sourceforge.io/apidoc/2.0/html/)

You may be using a recent NuGet package or a more up to date version in your project and that's why the IDE can't find it. Quartz.NET is on [version 3.0](https://quartznet.sourceforge.io/apidoc/3.0/html/) already. For sure the API changed a lot.

Comment: Thanks @Leniel for your kind answer. It resolves the collection issue but other issue arises like "IScheduler' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IScheduler' could be found"

Comment: This can help you a little bit: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49449685/114029 However... this all boils down to the library version you're using and the code you're trying to implement. They don't match. You'll have to adapt your current code.

Comment: Thanks @ Leniel finally I have fixed the problem which I mentioned in the earlier comment in this way **var dictionary = new Dictionary<IJobDetail, IReadOnlyCollection<ITrigger>>();

                dictionary.Add(jobDetail, new HashSet<ITrigger>()
                          {
                              trigger1,
                              trigger2
                          });
                Scheduler.ScheduleJobs(dictionary, true);
                Scheduler.Start();**

Answer (score -2):

As this blog post suggests ( https://www.koskila.net/how-to-fix-the-type-or-namespace-name-services-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsoft-aspnetcore-components-are-you-missing-an-assembly-reference/ ), downgrading Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design might help, or upgrade all of your packages to preview 9,  if this happened to you after updating your Visual Studio to Visual Studio 2019 16.3 Preview 3 (or presumably 16.2.4),